# MongoDB get child data

Tags: php, mongodb

i was testing some queries with mongodb and php

I have this data on the collection

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "icon": "task",
    "active": "1",
    "translations": [{
        "language": "en",
        "title": "Content title in English",
        "description": "Content description in English",
        "path": "content-english.html"
    }, {
        "language": "es",
        "title": "Content title in Spanish",
        "description": "Content description in Spanish",
        "path": "content-spanish.html"
    }]
}
```

What I need is to search the "path" property and get only the child that has the searched value.
For example, if I search for "content-english.html" I need this result

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "icon": "task",
    "active": "1",
        "title": "Content title in English",
    "description": "Content description in English",
    "path": "content-english.html"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this aggregation query:

- First `$match` to get only documents where exists your desired value into `translations` array.
- Then filter that array and get the first element (i.e. the object with `path` as your desired value)
- And last `$project` to get the data as you want.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "translations.path": "content-english.html"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "child": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          {
            "$filter": {
              "input": "$translations",
              "cond": {"$eq": ["$$this.path","content-english.html"]}
            }
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "id": 1,
      "icon": 1,
      "active": 1,
      "title": "$child.title",
      "description": "$child.description",
      "path": "$child.path"
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YWOFy27s6rj)

Comment: Thank you so much, I was trying with aggregate but didn't work yet, I try your solution and it works perfect!!